# Display tags in CSS interrupting with Jquery hide/show

Tags: jquery, css

Been trying to create this hide/show div with #mobile-menu hidden until you click the 'open'-link. Problem is that the centering vertically and horizontally styling is interfering with everything and messing it up, so it can't be hidden. Got any ideas on how to solve this? It can't be hidden with display: none; and it can't be hidden with jQuery...

Codes:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lmyrb64g/2/

```
$('#mobile-menu').hide();
$('.openmobile').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('#mobile-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Html

```
<style>
#mobile-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1111111111111;
}
#mobile-menu:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
  }
#mobile-menu #links {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: Cabin;
}
#mobile-menu #links a {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<div id="mobile-menu" class="visible-phone">
    <div id="links">
      <a href="http://eldeskin.com/collections/all">SKIN CARE</a>
      <a href="#">BODY CARE</a>
      <a href="#">MAKE-UP</a>
      <a class="search-show">SEARCH</a>     
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="openmobile">open</a>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do. I open your fiddle, click and it disappears. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @Leeish It dissapeared because you clicked on a link to a web-page. The #mobile-menu isn't supposed to show, but the jQuery doesn't work. #mobile-menu is not supposed to show until you click on the 'open' link... But I can't find a way to hide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were almost there: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmyrb64g/8/

try this code:

```
$('#mobile-menu').hide();

$('.openmobile').on('click', function(){
    $('#mobile-menu').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

and you forgot to include jQuery on the left side from the fiddle:

[image]

---

I'm NOT sure what you want to do with this code:

```
$('.openmobile').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('#mobile-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

`.openmobile` only exists once so no need to do `.each()` then further down

`$(this).next('#mobile-menu')` in this case `$(this)` would be on actually on the click which will not workg, but also if it would be `.openmobile` there is no `.next('#mobile-menu')`...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">       </script>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
 });
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
 });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```